# NGINX process are running and sites are being served but status & reload report errors

Tags: nginx

I'm having an issue where Nginx is running (as evidenced by the the output of `ps aux | grep nginx` and the websites are still being served) however a `service nginx reload` reports `nginx.service is not active, cannot reload`, and a `service nginx restart` reports `Job for nginx.service failed because the control process existed with error code.` As far as I can tell it nginx is getting in its own way. Details below:

```
$ ps aux | grep nginx

nginx     9485  0.0  0.0 558996 12172 ?        S<   Oct26   0:00 php-fpm: pool www
root     20558  0.0  0.0  14856  1008 pts/0    S+   21:36   0:00 grep --color=auto nginx
root     31852  0.0  0.2  73984 44976 ?        Ss   Nov03   0:00 nginx: master process nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
nginx    32003  0.3  0.2  78364 46288 ?        S    Nov03  44:05 nginx: worker process
nginx    32004  0.0  0.2  78364 46288 ?        S    Nov03   0:45 nginx: worker process
nginx    32005  0.0  0.2  78364 46284 ?        S    Nov03   0:02 nginx: worker process
nginx    32006  0.0  0.2  78364 46224 ?        S    Nov03   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx    32007  0.0  0.2  78364 45908 ?        S    Nov03   0:00 nginx: worker process
nginx    32008  0.0  0.2  78364 46012 ?        S    Nov03   0:00 nginx: worker process
```

```
$ systemctl status nginx

● nginx.service - nginx - high performance web server
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/nginx.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2020-11-12 21:24:46 UTC; 13min ago
     Docs: http://nginx.org/en/docs/
  Process: 19125 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/nginx -c /etc/nginx/nginx.conf (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 Main PID: 16146 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Nov 12 21:24:45 Jupiter nginx[19125]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 12 21:24:45 Jupiter nginx[19125]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 12 21:24:45 Jupiter nginx[19125]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 12 21:24:46 Jupiter nginx[19125]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 12 21:24:46 Jupiter nginx[19125]: nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
Nov 12 21:24:46 Jupiter nginx[19125]: nginx: [emerg] still could not bind()
Nov 12 21:24:46 Jupiter systemd[1]: nginx.service: Control process exited, code=exited status=1
Nov 12 21:24:46 Jupiter systemd[1]: nginx.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Nov 12 21:24:46 Jupiter systemd[1]: Failed to start nginx - high performance web server.
Nov 12 21:35:13 Jupiter systemd[1]: nginx.service: Unit cannot be reloaded because it is inactive.
```

```
$ lsof -i:80

COMMAND   PID  USER   FD   TYPE    DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx   31852  root  114u  IPv4 527474169      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   32003 nginx   18u  IPv4 543262507      0t0  TCP Jupiter:http->crawl-66-249-79-242.googlebot.com:50078 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   32003 nginx   36u  IPv4 543262529      0t0  TCP Jupiter:http->laubervilliers-658-1-213-130.w90-63.abo.wanadoo.fr:65226 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   32003 nginx  114u  IPv4 527474169      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   32003 nginx  139u  IPv4 543267901      0t0  TCP Jupiter:http->crawl-66-249-79-250.googlebot.com:43354 (ESTABLISHED)
nginx   32004 nginx  114u  IPv4 527474169      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   32005 nginx  114u  IPv4 527474169      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   32006 nginx  114u  IPv4 527474169      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   32007 nginx  114u  IPv4 527474169      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   32008 nginx  114u  IPv4 527474169      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Any idea whats going on and how to fix it?

Thanks in advance!